# Android Studio anim folder error: "File already exists"

Tags: android

I want to create an anim folder on android studio. I created a new android resource directory and chose anim as resource type and directory name, but still can't create it. Any idea ?  [image]

Edit : I tried to create an Android Resource file but when I press 'Ok' nothing happen. [image]

Comment: post any screenshot of the error?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal posted link to the screenshot

Comment: try naming that folder using a different name.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal if i name it different then it will not do the same thing, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on `res` folder and click on `Show in Explorer`.  
When the Explorer window opens double click the `res` folder.  
If you see the subfolder `anim` then you already have it.  
If not create it.  
Go back to AS, right click on `res` folder and choose `Synchronize 'res'`

Answer (score 1):

The error you posted says that `"Folder already exists"`

Try naming that folder using a different name. It will do the same thing as the other `anim` folders. It is the line of codes in the various files that we create inside a directory that provides animations not the directory folder's name. You can name the directory as you want.

Go ahead and name the folder by another name but make sure to access the director files as : `R.folder_name.file_name`

Comment: I should create an Android Resource file or an Android Resource directory ? And I must rename folder name, right ? ( for example, instead of anim I can place anim1, right ?)

Comment: @Mihai yes, exactly

Comment: And where I create the file? On Android Resource file or on Android Resource directory ?

Comment: actually the anim folder consists of resource files or xml files and these files make use of certain tags to provide animations

Comment: create the new resource file in the anime1 as now your folder is created.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as follows:

- Right-click your `res` folder the "New" > "Android Resource File"
- You'll be proposed a few properties:

  - File name: *whatever*
  - Resource type: **Animation**
  - Root elements: resources
  - Directory name: **anim**

Make sure you got those selected (especially the last one), as I works quite good for me.

Comment: I did and happen nothing when I press OK. The tab doesn't close and nothing change. Are you sure I should create resource file instead of resource directory ?

Comment: Yes I'm sure it always worked for me (I just tried). The screenshot you posted just says you already got an `anim` forlder... Maybe you should "Synchronize `res`" from the project explorer in Android Studio?

Comment: how can I do this ?

Comment: I edited the post with what I wrote on the Android Resource file

Answer (score 0):

I was just facing the same issue but I quickly resolved it. just follow my instructions.

1. Click on Android and then select packages option.
2. Search anim and delete.
3. Select  Android  again.
   4.Go to "res" package and then select "New" then  "android resource directory" and type "anim" and hit enter.
   you have done.